# Why is RZ-DPSK more nonlinear tolerant than NRZ-DPSK?

Tags: communication, modulation

In fiber optics, why would RZ-DPSK be more suited for long-haul transmissions over NRZ-DPSK? Is the tolerance to non-linearity due to the power intensity or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RZ-DPSK is derived from NRZ-DPSK via a pulse carver, so you can see that a carrier will be more available than from the constant envelope of the NRZ.  In NRZ the carrier arises from the phase shift chirps and non-linearities in that process.

Looking at the spectrum of the RZ vs. NRZ you will see a higher carrier to sideband ratio and a flatter power spectrum.  All good things for recovering the signal on the other end.

Answer (score 0):

At higher bit rates and long haul links RZ is more prone to  dispersion as compared to NRZ.

Comment: It might be worth adding a bit more context to make this a more useful answer.